# Single Label Multiple Values SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a requirement to assign either paid or pend label to a parameter in SSRS. When user selects paid it should pass two values to the stored procedure, 02 and 91 . If user selects pend it should pass all the remaining values to the stored procedure other than 02 and 91. How to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide yourt store procedure code. How many parameters on the report. if one paramater then store proc with work

Comment: Where are you getting the values to pass to the parameters ? Are they default ?